# Flying into Germany with a Luxembourg Type D Visa

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, luxembourg

I have a Type D (long-stay) visa issued by Luxembourg. Can I fly into Düsseldorf Airport in Germany, and them from Dusseldorf take a train to go to Luxembourg?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

A Type-D visa allows for the same provisions as a normal Schengen visa; that is you can visit the Schengen member states (and you are still bound to the 90/180 rule, along with other restrictions such as having enough money to support yourself, etc.)

Stay safe and enjoy your trip.